# Axios VueJS and open API

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, cors

I am tryng to get data from a API. But when I use Insomnia ou direct on browser, it is ok.

When I use axios in my code, I have this error : Blocking of a multi-origin request (Cross-Origin Request): the "Same Origin" policy does not allow to consult the remote resource....

My code

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL : 'https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants?token=********',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    withCredentials: false,
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers : {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
})


async getPlantsList(context)
        {
            try{            
                const response = await axiosInstance.get();

                console.log('2', response.data);

            } catch(error){
                console.log('error', error);
            }
        }
```

I need help, I search on web, but I do not find a solution.

Thank for your help

Add headers in  axios instance

Comment: Does the API **allow** cross-origin requests?  Where in their documentation or support information is this indicated?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` has no place in your request; it's a response header. Besides, you cannot use the `no-cors` mode if you want your client to have access to the response.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. The [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) has no place in your *request*, since it's a *response* header.
2. You cannot use the `no-cors` mode if you want your client to have access to the response. You'll have to use the `cors` mode (which is the default for cross-origin requests).
3. Because the resource in question doesn't seems to allow any request headers other than [*CORS-safelisted request headers*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header), you won't be able to include a `Content-Type` header in your request. But note that the request in question is a `GET`, for which it makes no sense to include a `Content-Type` header, since `GET` requests are not meant to have a body. Just drop that header from your request.

If you solve all three issues, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessary to set `cors` option

I will shows two options by axios call.
Both makes same result

Option 1 : using create()

```
const axios = require("axios")

const token ='<your token>'
const api = axios.create({baseURL: `https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants/?token=${token}`});

try {
    api.get().then((results) => {
        for (plant of results.data.data) { 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(plant))
        }
    })
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

Option 2 : no create()

```
const axios = require("axios")

const getPlants = async () => {
    try {
        const token ='<your token>'
        const response = await axios.get(`https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants?token=${token}`);
        return Promise.resolve(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

getPlants()
    .then(plants => {
        for (plant of plants.data) { 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(plant))
        }
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Result 1

```
$ node get-option1.js
{"id":77116,"common_name":"Evergreen oak","slug":"quercus-rotundifolia","scientific_name":"Quercus rotundifolia","year":1785,"bibliography":"Encycl. 1: 723 (1785)","author":"Lam.","status":"accepted","rank":"species","family_common_name":null,"genus_id":3519,"image_url":"https://d2seqvvyy3b8p2.cloudfront.net/40ab8e7cdddbe3e78a581b84efa4e893.jpg","synonyms":["Quercus ilex var. oleoides","Quercus ilex subvar. rotundifolia","Quercus ilex f. macrophylla","Quercus ilex f. oleoides","Quercus ilex var. calicina","Quercus ilex subsp. rotundifolia","Quercus lyauteyi","Quercus ballota var. rotundifolia","Quercus ilex f. brevicupulata","Quercus ilex subvar. major","Quercus ilex var. pendula","Quercus rotundifolia f. dolichocalyx","Quercus calicina","Quercus rotundifolia f. pilosella","Quercus rotundifolia f. macrocarpa","Quercus ilex var. rotundifolia","Quercus sugaro","Quercus ilex subvar. pendula","Quercus ilex f. pendula","Quercus ilex f. ballota","Quercus ilex f. rotundifolia","Quercus ilex subvar. minor","Quercus ballota","Quercus ilex var. ballota","Quercus ilex f. calicina","Quercus ilex var. microcarpa","Quercus rotundifolia f. calicina","Quercus ilex f. macrocarpa","Quercus rotundifolia f. brevicupulata","Quercus rotundifolia var. macrocarpa","Quercus ilex var. brevicupulata","Quercus ilex subsp. ballota","Quercus ilex var. dolichocalyx","Quercus rotundifolia var. pilosella","Quercus rotundifolia var. brevicupulata","Quercus rotundifolia subsp. maghrebiana"],"genus":"Quercus","family":"Fagaceae","links":{"self":"/api/v1/species/quercus-rotundifolia","plant":"/api/v1/plants/quercus-rotundifolia","genus":"/api/v1/genus/quercus"}}

... cut off
```

Result 2

```
$ node get-option2.js
{"id":77116,"common_name":"Evergreen oak","slug":"quercus-rotundifolia","scientific_name":"Quercus rotundifolia","year":1785,"bibliography":"Encycl. 1: 723 (1785)","author":"Lam.","status":"accepted","rank":"species","family_common_name":null,"genus_id":3519,"image_url":"https://d2seqvvyy3b8p2.cloudfront.net/40ab8e7cdddbe3e78a581b84efa4e893.jpg","synonyms":["Quercus ilex var. oleoides","Quercus ilex subvar. rotundifolia","Quercus ilex f. macrophylla","Quercus ilex f. oleoides","Quercus ilex var. calicina","Quercus ilex subsp. rotundifolia","Quercus lyauteyi","Quercus ballota var. rotundifolia","Quercus ilex f. brevicupulata","Quercus ilex subvar. major","Quercus ilex var. pendula","Quercus rotundifolia f. dolichocalyx","Quercus calicina","Quercus rotundifolia f. pilosella","Quercus rotundifolia f. macrocarpa","Quercus ilex var. rotundifolia","Quercus sugaro","Quercus ilex subvar. pendula","Quercus ilex f. pendula","Quercus ilex f. ballota","Quercus ilex f. rotundifolia","Quercus ilex subvar. minor","Quercus ballota","Quercus ilex var. ballota","Quercus ilex f. calicina","Quercus ilex var. microcarpa","Quercus rotundifolia f. calicina","Quercus ilex f. macrocarpa","Quercus rotundifolia f. brevicupulata","Quercus rotundifolia var. macrocarpa","Quercus ilex var. brevicupulata","Quercus ilex subsp. ballota","Quercus ilex var. dolichocalyx","Quercus rotundifolia var. pilosella","Quercus rotundifolia var. brevicupulata","Quercus rotundifolia subsp. maghrebiana"],"genus":"Quercus","family":"Fagaceae","links":{"self":"/api/v1/species/quercus-rotundifolia","plant":"/api/v1/plants/quercus-rotundifolia","genus":"/api/v1/genus/quercus"}}
... cut off
```

[image]

Comment: My origianl is that 

actions:{
        async getPlantsList(context)
        {
            try{
                console.log(axiosInstance);        
                const response = await axiosInstance.get();

                console.log('2', response.data);
                context.commit();

            } catch(error){
                console.log('error', error);
            }
        }
I have always an error

Answer (score 0):

Is someone could take a time to explain me why my code does not work ?

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL : `https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants?token=${token}`,
})

actions:{
        async getPlantsList(context)
        {
            try{
                console.log(axiosInstance);        
                const response = await axiosInstance.get();

                console.log('2', response.data);
                context.commit();

            } catch(error){
                console.log('error', error);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer

With Vuejs 3

On `vite.config.js` file in root.

You have to add this code

```
server:{
  proxy:{
    '/api':{
      target: 'https://trefle.io',
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  }
```

https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html

Thanks for helping me